# Queue messages that are moved to Poison Queue still show as queue count, but stay hidden

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am testing the Poison message handling of the Webjob that I am building.

Everything seems to be working as expected except, one strange thing:

When a message is moved to the “-poison” queue, its ghost seems to remain hidden (invisible) in the main job queue. That means if I have 6 poison messages moved to the “-poison” queue, storage explorer shows “**Showing 0 of 6 messages in queue**”. I can not see the 6 hidden messages in the Storage Explorer.

I tried to delete the job queue and recreating it, but the strange issue still happening after I run my tests. Storage explorer shows “Showing 0 of 6 messages in queue”.

What is happening behind the scene?

**Update 1**

I did some investigation and I think WebJob SDK does not delete the poison message.

I went through WebJob SDK source code and I think this line of code is not being executed for some reason:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Queues/QueueProcessor.cs#L119

Here is my Function that can help reproducing the issue:

```
public class Functions
{
    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("%QueueName%")] string message, TextWriter log)
    {
        if (message.Contains("Break"))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Error while processing message {message}");
        }

        log.WriteLine($"Processed message {message}");
    }

}
```

**Update 2**

Here is the WebJob SDK I am using:

[image]

Comment: Does the "6" show on Storage Explorer only? The problem might be there only

Comment: @pollirrata, Storage Explorer always shows and accurate proper count. So it is not known what is special with the messages that WebJob SDK moves to -poison queue? Do they have special hidden flag?

Comment: As far as I know, the webjob SDK will call a function up to 5 times(Default value) to process a queue message. If the fifth try fails, the message is moved to a poison queue. So the queue message will delete and move to the poison queue. I also write a test demo on my computer, it works well. Could you please post your webjob's function and config codes. It will help us to reproduce your issue and find solution.

Comment: @BrandoZhang-MSFT, thank you for help. I updated my question, hopefully, it help you with re-producing the issue. Please let me know if you need any detail.

Comment: I have written a test according to your codes, it works well. If I add a "AAABreak" queue message to the "queue", it will move the message to the "queue-poison" queue. Could you please tell me what webjob SDK version you used and the post more details code in the program.cs's main method?

Comment: @BrandoZhang-MSFT. Please note that moving the message to poison queue is not the problem. The problem is that SDK does not delete the position message, so it keeps coming back when its invisibility time is over.  Can you please confirm that you do not get the "Showing 0 of 6 messages in queue" in storage explorer when 6 messages are moved to the Poison queue? Thank you for help.

Comment: I test it on local side and azure, it all works well. It will move the message to the poison queue and delete the queue message. Could you please share your project in the onedrive, I will download it and test it on my side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141406/discussion-between-brando-zhang-msft-and-allan-xu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the azure storage SDK 8.+  is not work well with the Azure webjobs SDK2.0 ([related issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1107)).

If you use storage SDK 8.+ the poison messages stay undeleted-but-invisible.

Workaround method is using the low azure storage SDK 7.2.1.

It will work well.

And this issue will be solved in the future SDK version.

Comment: Was this ultimately fixed in the later versions of the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

The problem is when then Message copy in poison queue pass by ref without visibility time https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Queues/QueueProcessor.cs#L145 and when try to delete the message from original queue the service returns 404 not found. Is a problem in azure-webjobs-sdk and the solution is to make this change

```
await AddMessageAndCreateIfNotExistsAsync(poisonQueue, new CloudQueueMessage(message.AsString), cancellationToken);
```

in https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Queues/QueueProcessor.cs#L145
we wait new version with this fix

**Custom solution**

To solve this create your own CustomProcessor and in **CopyMessageToPoisonQueueAsync** function create new CloudMessage from original to pass in poison queue, see example below.

```
var config = new JobHostConfiguration
config.Queues.QueueProcessorFactory = new CustomQueueProcessorFactory();

public QueueProcessor Create(QueueProcessorFactoryContext context)
    {
        // demonstrates how the Queue.ServiceClient options can be configured
        context.Queue.ServiceClient.DefaultRequestOptions.ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

        // demonstrates how queue options can be customized
        context.Queue.EncodeMessage = true;

        // return the custom queue processor
        return new CustomQueueProcessor(context);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Custom QueueProcessor demonstrating some of the virtuals that can be overridden
    /// to customize queue processing.
    /// </summary>
    private class CustomQueueProcessor : QueueProcessor
    {
        private QueueProcessorFactoryContext _context;
        public CustomQueueProcessor(QueueProcessorFactoryContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public override async Task CompleteProcessingMessageAsync(CloudQueueMessage message, FunctionResult result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await base.CompleteProcessingMessageAsync(message, result, cancellationToken);
        }
        protected override async Task CopyMessageToPoisonQueueAsync(CloudQueueMessage message, CloudQueue poisonQueue, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var msg = new CloudQueueMessage(message.AsString);
            await base.CopyMessageToPoisonQueueAsync(msg, poisonQueue, cancellationToken);
        }
        protected override void OnMessageAddedToPoisonQueue(PoisonMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMessageAddedToPoisonQueue(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone out there still having this issue. This should be fixed since [2.1.0-beta1-10851](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/releases/tag/v2.1.0-beta1-10851). The downside is that there is currently no stable released version of 2.1.0 yet.

Comment: Was this fixed?

Comment: Given that we have a 2.2.0 stable version this should be fixed by now but I haven't tested it yet.